# Creating a molecular cloud in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I'm currently teaching myself design and have been asked to create a molecular cloud similar to that in the attached image.  I'm seeking advice on how one might obtain a similar result/effect in Photoshop.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Noise on a layer with a mask.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is fairly simple. Here are some key points:

**STEP 1 -** I first drew a random 1px line with the pentool.

[image]

**STEP 2 -** I used `mask` and `brush tool + soft round brush` to fade parts of it slightly.

[image]

**STEP 3 -** Then I drew bunch of dots in every corner. They vary in size.

[image]

**STEP 4 -** Then I made a brush out of it.

**STEP 5 -** Adjusted the brush settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**STEP 58 -** Now if you use `ellipse tool` to make a `path` and use `stroke path + brush tool`, you get something like this:

You will want to `stroke path` multiple times with different brush sizes. Of course for realzies, you'd want to use more than one brush.

[image]

**STEP 380 -** ...and after inverting colors, adding bunch of highlights, duplicating the brush pattern multiple times, using different blend modes and using `filters > blur > tilt-shift` to blur some of it...  this is what you get:

[image]

Comment: Joonas.  Thankyou so much for such a comprehensive answer!  Wow.. You've totally made my day. Thankyou! :D

Comment: Wow, you nailed it. Great answer.

Comment: @Joonas Nice answer dude, its a copy of the original.