# How to make a ring of Circles in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, shapes

I am trying to make something like this, where the large circle is composed of many smaller circles, and there is also a gradient of color and brightness from the center of the ring outward.  There is some randomness in the smaller circles, and they don't overlap.

Any ideas? I have not found anything helpful yet.

[image: Ring of smaller Circles]

Comment: Err.. what do you expect the anwer to be? Photoshop is q direct modeler, so you would paint each gradient disk separately.

Comment: I guess I am not sure what I expected the answer to be.  So you think I would have to build up the rings manually, from the inside out?

Comment: The reference image is like 20x20px, I only see noise... If I wanted to make what you're describing I'd rather use a software that supports particle systems, for example After Effects or Blender — this way it'd be possible to easily control spread, count, color. If you want to paint those, create a brush with several circles in it and random rotation and start painting with different colors.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm seeing enough details to know what exactly is going on with the image, but it looks like it's not just uniform noise, but some smaller and bigger dots and so I would probably go with the "technique" in this answer (...just leave out the lines): https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37514/creating-a-molecular-cloud-in-photoshop/37521#37521

Comment: Thanks, I think that helps me... I was trying to figure out the best tool for the job, and Photoshop is not really suited for this.  I'll see what I can do with Blender or After Effects.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of this one: [Creating a molecular cloud in Photoshop](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37514/creating-a-molecular-cloud-in-photoshop)